# Android: Record video in the same orientation regardless of device orientation

Tags: android, video, record

On my Android 2.3 device, the standard camera app always records a video in same orientation regardless how the device is rotated. If you record a video in landscape mode, it always records the video with the same orientation even if you turn it upside down. Same for portrait mode. However, if you rotate the video while recording, you will get it upside down, which is what one expects. The camera app only adjusts the rotation to always be "up" prior to the actual recording. If you rotate the camera prior to recording, you'll even see that the camera control icons rotate as well to always face up.

While the camera app can adjust the rotation as the user rotates their device, it is not required to do this. You can restart your device with any orientation and never change it, and the camera app will still know which way is up. It doesn't require a change listener. What I want to do is the same thing. However, my app is a service. No activity is ever used. I can already record a video in the service.

I cannot seem to get the video to rotate to always be up. I have tried:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters;
parameters.setRotation
```

as well as:

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation
```

Neither worked. The solution must run on API 8 and above.

Comment: How do you get the orientation? Is it possible that the actual value you are setting is always the same? `parameters.setRotation` should do it.

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/39271585/1495839
You can find solution